# Requested product doesn't exist Magento 2.1.8 after migration

Tags: catalog, magento-2.1.8

I have migrated data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1.8. Almost all products working fine except some products are displayed in the frontend but when I will edit one product in admin than its showing me "Requested product doesn't exist" error.

Only some products have this issue?

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: please check whether the product id is there in DB or not. Based on that issue can be traced.

Comment: Product Id is available in DB. Product is visible for frontend and as well as product grid.

Comment: Have you guys get any solution for this ?